# TFS - Is it possible to rollback a changeset committed before the branching?

Tags: branch, rollback, changeset

Suppose I Branch Solution-A, changeset 10 into Solution-B.

Later on, I realize Solution-B should not have changeset 7 in it.

Is there a way to rollback changeset 7 just from Solution B without harming solution A?

Whenever I use tf rollback, all the pending changes go to Solution-A.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rollback the changeset that has the merges to solution b, and then reapply the merge without changeset 7.

Comment: There are many merges done since that commit(the one which I have to rollback) and that changeset lies in a grand grand grand parent branch :(

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but this may help anybody who has the same problem. Especially when you need to rollback a changeset, which was checked in long ago on another branch.

Update WORKSPACE_ROOT and TFS_BRANCH_ROOT in the following batch file.
Name it e.g. RollbackMigrate.cmd and run it always from the workspace root.

This batch file will:

1. Parse arguments - only one argument is the change set number
2. Find the name of current workspace and it's path on TFS
3. Find the TFS source path for migration
4. Map the source into current workspace
5. Rollback the change set
6. Create shelve set and undo check out
7. Remove the temporary mapping
8. Unshelve the previously created shelve set and migrate it

   - you just need to auto merge the shelveset in a new window
9. Delete the temporary shelve set
10. Checkin

    - you just need to update the comment, notes and work item link

---

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set WORKSPACE_ROOT=D:\PathToMyWorkspaces
set TFS_BRANCH_ROOT=$/Project/Branches

:01_ARGUMENT_PARSING
echo Rollback changes from another branch
if [%1]==[] (
    set /P CHANGESET=Enter changeset number: 
    if [!CHANGESET!]==[] (
        echo Changeset number is required! Exiting!
        exit /B 1
    )
) else (
    set CHANGESET=%1
    shift
)
set SHELVE_NAME="Auto shelved rollback of %CHANGESET%"

:02_FIND_MY_WORKSPACE_NAME
for %%i in (.) do (
    set WORKSPACE=%%~nxi
)
if not [%CD%]==[%WORKSPACE_ROOT%\%WORKSPACE%] (
    echo This script works only in the root of workspace e.g. D:\PathToMyWorkspaces\MyWorkspace
    exit /B 1
)
echo Current workspace is %WORKSPACE%
for /f %%i in ('tf workspaces %WORKSPACE% /noprompt /format:detailed ^| grep -om 1 "$/[^:]\+"') do (
    if not [%DST%]==[] (
        echo Cannot work on workspaces with more mappings! Exiting!
        exit /B 2
    )
    set DST=%%i
    echo Found destination path for migration: "%%i"
)

:03_VIEW_CHANGESET
for /f %%i in ('tf changeset 1570888 ^| grep -om 1 "%TFS_BRANCH_ROOT%/[^/]\+/[^/]\+"') do (
    set SRC=%%i
    echo Found source path for migration: "%%i"
)
if [%SRC%]==[] (
    echo Cannot find path to source branch! Exiting!
    exit /B 3
)
for %%i in (%SRC%) do (
    set SRC_BRANCH=%%~nxi
)

:04_MAP_SOURCE
set TMP_SRC_PATH=%WORKSPACE_ROOT%\%WORKSPACE%_%SRC_BRANCH%
echo Create temporary mapping for source branch in %TMP_SRC_PATH%
mkdir %TMP_SRC_PATH%
echo Creating mapping for "%SRC%" to "%TMP_SRC_PATH%"
tf workfold /map %SRC% %TMP_SRC_PATH%
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    echo Can't create mapping for "%SRC%", exiting!
    exit /B 4
)

:05_ROLLBACK_CHANGESET
echo Performing rollback of changeset %CHANGESET%
tf rollback /changeset:%CHANGESET% /lock:checkin /keepmergehistory

:06_SHELVE_ROLLBACK
echo Shelving rollback
tf shelve /comment:%SHELVE_NAME% %SHELVE_NAME% /noprompt /move /replace

:07_UNMAP_AND_DELETE_TEMPORARY
echo Unmapping "%SRC%" from "%TMP_SRC_PATH%"
tf workfold /unmap "%TMP_SRC_PATH%"
echo Deleting "%TMP_SRC_PATH%"
rmdir /S /Q "%TMP_SRC_PATH%"

:08_UNSHELVE_MIGRATE
echo Unshelving the rollback...
tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:"%SRC%" /target:"%DST%" %SHELVE_NAME% /noprompt

:09_DELETE_THE_SHELVESET
echo Deleting the shelveset
tf shelve /delete %SHELVE_NAME% /noprompt

:10_CHECKIN
echo Checking in the rollback...
tf checkin
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the TFPT.exe which comes with the power tools pack: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/

High level overview:

1. From the workspace mapping of Solution-B rollback the changeset
2. Commit the change for the workspace mapping in Solution-B

Commands:

1. c:\workspace\mapping\to\solution\b> tfpt rollback /changeset:7
2. c:\workspace\mapping\to\solution\b> tf commit

Comment: I think they removed rollback from power tools as soon as they got it on tf.exe... I tried using tf rollback in the workspace mapping and I got a message "nothing to rollback", or something along these lines.

Comment: there is no `tfpt rollback` command and there isn't any `tf commit` command either.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did something like below.

1. Rollback changeset 7 on Solution-A and checkin. This will create changeset 11 on Solution-A
2. Merge the changeset 11 to Solution-B branch
3. Rollback changes 11 on Solution-A branch and checkin which will create changeset 12 on Solution-A

In future merges to Solution-B from Solution-A skip merging changeset 12.